# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-03-26 1624:32:39"

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm generating a date string using the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mm:ss`. However, when I attempt to parse the resulting string I get an error:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-03-26 1624:32:39"

Full example:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatterAPITS = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 30); // add 30 days
Date newExpirationDate = dateFormatterAPITS.parse(
                           dateFormatterAPITS.format(cal.getTime())
                         );
```

Comment: are you sure you want to use HH24? isn't just `HH` for a 24-hour format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mm:ss` to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

More information about [Date and Time Patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: what should be done if i want the date as "2015-09-09T00:00:00". I am not sure what the T stands for. but its required

Comment: @user1861033 `T` is not part of the pattern, but if you need it then you escape it with single quotes for example: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`